# SwiftUI: NavigationLinkで遷移後の画面でデータを更新すると前に戻される

Tags: swift, ios, swiftui

Swiftについて以下の内容について困っております。

### 発生したこと

NavigationLinkで2回遷移できる以下のようなアプリを作成しました。
[image: ダメな例]

上記の通り挙動としては

1. `subsubへ`で`SubsubTestView`に遷移(`SubsubTestView`のViewModelは`SubTestView`で渡してます)
2. リストのどれかを指定すると、`DetailView`に遷移
3. 編集して`submit`を押すと強制的に`SubsubTestView(ListのView)`に戻される ← ★これが問題

ソースコードは以下です

- TestApp.swift

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
          ContentView().environmentObject(EnvObj())
        }
    }
}
```

- ContentView.swift

```swift
import SwiftUI

class EnvObj: ObservableObject {
  @Published var users = [User(name: "a"), User(name: "b"), User(name: "c")]
}

struct User: Hashable, Identifiable, Equatable {
  var id = UUID()
  var name = ""
  
  static func == (lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool{
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var envObj: EnvObj
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        NavigationLink("subsubへ", destination: SubsubTestView(vm: VM(envObj: envObj)))
      }
    }
  }
}

struct SubsubTestView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var envObj: EnvObj
  @ObservedObject var vm: VM
  
  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(self.vm.envObj.users) { user in
        NavigationLink(
          user.name,
          destination: DetailView(vm: self.vm.vmd),
          tag: user,
          selection: self.$vm.vmd.selectedUser
        )
        .onTapGesture {
          self.vm.vmd.selectedUser = user
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

class VM: ObservableObject {
  var envObj: EnvObj = .init()
  @Published var vmd: VMD = .init()
  
  init(envObj: EnvObj) {
    self.envObj = envObj
    self.vmd.envObj = envObj
  }
}

struct DetailView: View {
  @ObservedObject var vm: VMD
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      TextField("名前", text: (self.$vm.selectedUser ?? User()).name)
      Text(self.vm.selectedUser?.name ?? User().name)
      Button("submit", action: self.vm.submit)
    }
  }
}

class VMD: ObservableObject {
  var envObj: EnvObj = .init()
  @Published var selectedUser: User?
  
  private(set) lazy var submit = {
    if let user = self.selectedUser {
      self.update(user: user)
    }
  }
  
  func update(user: User) {
    self.envObj.users = self.envObj.users.map {
      return $0 == user ? user : $0
    }
  }
}

func ??<T>(binding: Binding<T?>, fallback: T) -> Binding<T> {
  return Binding(get: {
    binding.wrappedValue ?? fallback
  }, set: {
    binding.wrappedValue = $0
  })
}
```

### お聞きしたいこと

- 強制的に戻る現象の理由と解決方法を知りたいです。

### こちらで試したこと

- 最初の`subsubへ`の行程をなくしてみたら、更新後の強制的な遷移は無くなりました。(EnvironmentObjectの設定のため一覧ページのVMが若干変わっています)

```swift
class VM2: ObservableObject {
  @Published var envObj: EnvObj = .init()
  @Published var vmd: VMD = .init()
  var settingDone = false
  
  func setting(envObj: EnvObj) {
    if !settingDone {
      self.envObj = envObj
      self.vmd.envObj = envObj
      self.settingDone = true
    }
  }
}

struct EnvTestView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var envObj: EnvObj
  @ObservedObject var vm: VM2 = .init()
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        ForEach(self.vm.envObj.users, id: \.id) { user in
          NavigationLink(
            user.name,
            destination: DetailView(vm: self.vm.vmd),
            tag: user,
            selection: self.$vm.vmd.selectedUser
          )
          .onTapGesture {
            self.vm.vmd.selectedUser = user
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .onAppear(perform: {
      self.vm.setting(envObj: envObj)
    })
  }
}
```

長文申し訳ないです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「ソースコードは以下です」に示されたコードは`DetailView`でビルドエラーとなるため、現象を再現することができません。確実に「発生したこと」が再現されるようなコードに修正していただけませんか。

Comment: @OOPer 申し訳ありません。一部欠けていたので追記いたしました。

Comment: 修正ありがとうございます。ご記載の現象を再現することができました。SwiftUI的でないことを無理にやっているせいで、コードがどんどん複雑化して、動作が理解できなくなるという典型例のようですね。「各Viewが必ずしもviewModelを持つ必要はない」なんて回答は受け入れられますか?

Comment: @OOPer ありがとうございます。確かにEnvironmentObjectはVMを使ったMVVMで使うべきではない、というコメントもこちら( https://stackoverflow.com/a/60883764/8461565 )にありますし実装で遭遇した際は大人しくSwiftUIの書き方に則った方法で記述するようにいたします。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。正直そこら辺は現在のSwift言語/SwiftUIの不備とも言える事柄に起因するものであり、将来は違うやり方が主流になる可能性もあるでしょう。ただ、それまでの間、理解不能な挙動を示すようなやり方に無理やり継ぎ接ぎを当てて特定のパターンに当てはめるような書き方をするより、現在の「SwiftUIの書き方」に従ったほうが、コードがすっきりして保守性も高くなるだろうと思います。ぜひ現在のSwiftUIで所望の動作が実現できた際には自己回答をお願いします。